# How to run a Service every X minutes even if the app is not running

Tags: java, android, service, scheduled-tasks, android-9.0-pie

I would like to make an app that run a Service every 10 minutes when the app is not running. I've used an AlarmManager and a BroadcastReceiver to achieve this but the BroadcastReceiver is triggering only when the app is running. It's been a month I'm trying to figure out what's the problem, tried to make my service a foreground service, etc. but nothing worked. I've read a lot of similar questions about this but most of them are outdated and doesn't apply to my case. So here I am. How to run a task every 10 (or whatever, doesn't matter) minutes, even if the app is not running? Is the Doze-mode the reason I can't achieve this?

Comment: You might want to look into WorkManager: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: This seems very interesting, thanks! But can I use it even if my project doesn't support Android Jetpack?

Comment: AndroidX jetpack is supported very well. You won't have any issues.